# NAA flag declined on an answer that a mod later removed

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I recently flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128662/spring-security-allow-access-only-users-with-specific-username/60614588#60614588) as NAA ([Sentinel record](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/198303) for those under 10k), because it should have been a comment. It had previously made it through a removal review (3x Recommend Deletion), so I figured it was safe to re-flag. But not only was my flag declined, the post was deleted anyway (I assume by the mod that handled my flag).

Did I flag incorrectly? Was there some other reason it got deleted, and my NAA flag was just incorrect? I believe I was right in flagging as NAA, so if I need any correction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Two different mods... (Now three, if you count me, but why would you count me?)

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, good to know. I can't see the post now that it's removed, so even if I knew who denied the flag it wouldn't have helped. And I always count you, Cody <3

Comment: In regards to your edit, that is not possible. Only red flags (spam or rude/abusive) can have their status retroactively changed to “disputed”. Other types of flags can’t really be disputed by moderators, and definitely can’t have their dispensation changed later.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable use of the NAA flag to me.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, I didn't know that feature was limited to red flags. Appreciate the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declined it because it was an actual attempt at answering: the answer being *you are doing it wrong, you should instead use `/messages` and determine the current user inside the route*. It was not a post asking for clarifications or any of the other NAA flag reasons.

Another moderator, probably looking at the flag queue loaded around the same point in time when I declined the flag, decided to delete the post instead. It happens, we are human (rumours of some of us being AI programs in the cloud notwithstanding) after all. A fellow moderator pointed out to me that the deletion came *before* my decline, but the [current issues with automatic flag handling on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344919/post-deleted-but-not-an-answer-flag-is-still-pending) caused the flag to still be active by the time I declined it.

The answer wasn’t *great*, so I’ll not overturn the deletion.

Comment: *rumours of some of us being AI programs in the cloud notwithstanding* - haha... nice try but you don't fool me :)

Comment: Flags should not be declined if corrective action is taken on a post.  It doesn't matter how *precisely* the flag is used if the corrective action (that would have resulted from the flag had it been correctly applied) was taken anyway.

Comment: The point is, @Robert, Martijn didn't think the post was in need of corrective action by a moderator. Also, although your argument here seems reasonable on its face, I'm not sure how that squares with the common decline reason "you should have used a standard flag". Would you say that's an exception?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I **didn't take corrective action**. I'm not sure why you think I declined the flag and then did something else as well.

Comment: "the answer wasn't great" is an understatement. I deleted it, and I don't think it should be edited+undeleted to make it look more like an answer given that there's a +5 accepted answer besides that one. Not worth the time. And yes, there was this annoying bug yesterday that kept the flags unresolved even on deletion.

Comment: @CodyGray: Frankly, I'm not a fan of  the "you should have used a standard flag" thing. A flag is valid if it points out a problem post; mods shouldn't care how a problem post is brought to their attention unless they can't figure out why it's a problem post.  Custom moderator flags that describe the actual problem can be more valuable than the "standard" ones.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the only problem with this post, in my view, is that it was an answer mis-reported as NAA. The correct action in that case is to dismiss the flag.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: it's a different option to consider, and so a valid attempt at an answer. I actually agree that that's probably a better option than the X-Y problem the question asks to solve, and the only problem with it is that the author wasn't able to communicate this very effectively. But that's just my opinion, and this is not a tech stack I am familiar with. Did you make a tech call on this that this was not a solution worth considering?

Comment: I'm otherwise going to *move on*, because I don't think this post is worth the attention it has now received.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, I don't know the tech either. The post contains generic advice along with "asking for clarification/try this" questions, that was enough for me. I also agree that it's time to move on. Your answer explains what happened. Good, thanks for that.